# Matlab - how to do a near field / far field transformation

Tags: matlab, fft, octave

I would like to do a *near field - far field* transformation with MATLAB. I am using the software tool Feko to model my patch antenna and to get the [near field data](http://www.filedropper.com/resultsnf). With this data, I can display a plane that shows the near E-field of my microstrip antenna (at z = 5mm).

At the moment, I just put Re(Ex)+i.Im(Ex), Re(Ey)+i.Im(Ey) and Re(Ez)+i.Im(Ez) in the same matrix.

I know I should use fft or something like "plane wave spectrum" but I don't know how.

In the end, I would like to display a plane that shows the far E-field (z = 500mm for example).

Any idea to help me would be welcome !

Thank you

Here is the [code](http://www.filedropper.com/fft) with what I have done, and comments to explain it.

```
clear all

%% GET NEAR-FIELD DATAS FROM FEKO AND DELETE COMMENTS

[ficname,pathname] = uigetfile('*.efe','fichier ''.efe'' a convertir ?');
nomfic = [pathname ficname];
i0 = find(ficname=='.');
system(['sed -e "/^#/d;/^*/d" ',' "',nomfic,'"| tr -s " " " " > result.txt']);  
A = load('result.txt');

%% DISPLAY THE E NEAR-FIELD  

X = A(:,1);
Y = A(:,2);
Z = A(:,3);
aux = A(:,4:9);
Ex = sqrt((aux(:,1).^2 + aux(:,2).^2));
Ey = sqrt((aux(:,3).^2 + aux(:,4).^2));
%%Ez = sqrt((aux(:,5).^2 + aux(:,6).^2));
Etot = sqrt(Ex.^2+Ey.^2);

%% Grid interpolation (meshgrid)
patchd = 28 .* 0.001;
patchw = 43 .* 0.001;
pas = 0.5 .* 0.001;

xmin = -patchw/2;
xmax = patchw/2;
pasx = pas;

ymin = -patchd/2;
ymax = patchd/2;
pasy = pas;

[xq,yq] = meshgrid(xmin:pasx:xmax,ymin:pasy:ymax);
EInterp = griddata(X,Y,Etot,xq,yq);

figure(1);
surf(xq,yq,EInterp);
caxis([1 90]);
view(0,90);

%% TRANSFORMATION NEAR-FIELD FAR-FIELD


%% This is where I need to do an FFT on my near-field datas

Ex_im = aux(:,1)+i*aux(:,2);
Ey_im = aux(:,3)+i*aux(:,4);
Ez_im = aux(:,5)+i*aux(:,6);

N = 1024;
E_im = [Ex_im Ey_im];


%%C = fftshift(abs(fft2(E_im,N)));
%%C = fftshift(fft(fftshift(E_im,N)));


%% DISPLAY THE E FAR-FIELD

%% I will see later

%%surf(20*log10(C));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only two field components are needed when implementing plane wave spectrum method.

I suppose you are going to use Ex and Ey from frequency domain at a height of z=5mm to calculate Ex, Ey and Ez at z'=500mm.

- Calculate kx,ky and kz:

  kx range from -pi/X to pi/X and ky from -pi/Y to pi/Y. X and Y are lengths of the plane. kz can be calculated use following equation.

  [Equation of kz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1N1Lo.png)
- Calculate FEx and FEy at z=5mm:

  This can be easily done using Matlab.

  ```
   FEx=ifftshift(ifft2(Ex));

   FEy=ifftshift(ifft2(Ey));
  ```
- Calculate FEz at z=5mm:

  [Equation of FEz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwyEG.png)
- Calculate FEx, FEy, FEz at z'=500mm:

  ```
   FEx_500=FEx.*exp(-1i*kz*(z'-z));

   FEy_500=FEy.*exp(-1i*kz*(z'-z));

   FEz_500=FEz.*exp(-1i*kz*(z'-z));
  ```
- Calculate Ex, Ey, Ez at z'=500mm:

  ```
   Ex_500=fft2(fftshift(FEx_500));

   Ey_500=fft2(fftshift(FEy_500));

   Ez_500=fft2(fftshift(FEz_500));
  ```

There are some references you may feel interested to take a look:

1. Investigation on Planar Near-to-Far-Field Transformations for EMC Applications
2. Plane wave spectrum theory applied to nearfield measurements for electromagnetic compatibility investigations

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this question. The first is "how do I obtain the far fields given the near fields?" and the second is "how do I implement that in MATLAB?"

A lot of the time matlab has a builtin function that performs specialised procedures like these so the answer can be 'use function xyz' but in this case I don't know of one.

As it's not trivial I would suggest spending a bit of time researching that. Search the MATLAB documentation first to see if they provide you with a function. Failing that see if someone else has implemented it already - the [Mathworks file exchange](http://www.mathworks.es/matlabcentral/fileexchange/) often has third-party tools that do well-defined but complex tasks like this, for instance [here](http://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/index?utf8=%E2%9C%93&term=near%20field%20far%20field) are some results.

If it hasn't been implemented already to your satisfaction, or you have a requirement to produce your own code (commercial application, homework problem etc.), then you'll have to implement it yourself. To do it from first principles you will need an electromagnetics textbook - I like [Collin, Field Theory of Guided Waves](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0879422378.html) - but the derivations have already been done so you will probably find it more useful to start in the middle somewhere with something like [this](http://www.eecs.wsu.edu/~schneidj/ufdtd/chap14.pdf).

That handles the modelling aspect. The implementation is then about usage of MATLAB to achieve the procedure you've defined. If you need help with that part then make sure you include details of the algorithm you're trying to build as well as what you've managed to get working so far.

Comment: I have already checked the Mathworks exchange but all the subjects are often more complicated
than the one I am looking for. Plus, books and theory are very helpfull but they give complicated equations that I
don't really need for my code, I know I should use FFT but I don't know how with MATLAB. Maybe I was
not clear enough.

I've edited my first post to add my code.

Comment: If you can describe the operation you want to perform then I'll have a go at implementing it in matlab. Do be detailed in that description, as they say the devil is in the details.

Comment: I have edited my first post with links that can let you download my files.

What I need to do is :

- calculate the far-field with a simple FFT on my complex data (frequency domain) and display the far-field (the same way as the near-field in my code), it means that I should go back to the time domain ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Sorry you misunderstand me: if you already know the mathematical procedure then you should write that out in the question - in detail - so that people can help you convert that to matlab code. If you don't know the mathematical procedure then you could either post a new question or alter the existing one so that it makes it clear that that's what you want help with, but 'a simple FFT' is what you already have, so it's not clear what's missing.

Comment: You're right, I'll try a new post with the mathematical procedure.

Answer (score 0):

In case that your input data are in power (from s21 trace obtained with VNA), the NF_FF transformation is correct like this?

Ex = sqrt((s21_x_real.^2 + s21_x_imag.^2));
Ey = sqrt((s21_y_real.^2 + s21_y_imag.^2));

FEx=ifftshift(ifft2(Ex));
FEy=ifftshift(ifft2(Ey));

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).